# Finding the number of values of $\theta$ in the range $0 \le \theta \lt 2 \pi$ in the following simultaneous trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Source: MAT $2008$

Q. The following simultaneous equations are solvable for how many values of $\theta$ in the range $0 \le \theta \lt 2 \pi$?
$$(\cos \theta)x - (sin\theta)y = 2$$
$$(\sin\theta)x + (\cos\theta)y = 1$$

Eliminating $y$ from the equations, we get
$$x = 2\cos\theta + \sin\theta$$
Finding $y$ in terms of $x$, we get
$$y = \frac{(\cos\theta)x - 2}{sin\theta}, \; \sin\theta \neq 0$$
Since $\sin\theta \neq 0, \, 0 \, \text{and} \, \pi$ cannot be values of $\theta$. Hence, all except $2$ values of $\theta$ in the specified range render the simultaneous equations solvable.

This is an incorrect conclusion, since all values of $\theta$ will work in the specified range. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: @geetha290krm then I might have made an incorrect assumption, since the answer key says that the equations are solvable for all values of $\theta$

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment! The answer is correct and you have solved it. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Linear algebra also gives an easy answer. It tells you how to get a unique solution to the system of equations for any given $\theta$.

Comment: Hint: When, in general, is a system like
$$Ax + By = 2$$
$$Dx + Dy = 1$$
solvable?

Comment: @geetha290krm When I find $y$ in terms of $x$, $\sin \theta$ is in the denominator, so it cannot be zero, so $\theta$ cannot be $0$ or $\pi$. This is my conclusion. But the equations are solvable for all values of $\theta$. So why am I getting that they are unsolvable for $0$ and $\pi$?

Comment: Solve the equations separately for the case $\sin \theta =0$.